# How to update multiple fields with NEST (Elasticsearch) UpdateByQuery?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using UpdateByQuery, I want to update multiple fields. In Elasticsearch documentation it tells how to update a particular field.
How to do it?

Comment: In [this documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-examples.html) it shows a multiple update like: `"ctx._source.last = params.last; ctx._source.nick = params.nick"` - have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Nest you should use DocAsUpsert. In order to do that do a query first, get the _id of the doc then update based on that.
Small example here, update by id:

```
 var updateResponse = EsClient.Update<Business, object>(DocumentPath<Business>.Id(elasticId), u => u
                         .Index(_elasticIndex)
                         .Type("business")
                         .Doc(new Business { Field1 ="xxxx", Field2 ="yyyy" })
                         .DocAsUpsert()
                         .Refresh(Refresh.True)
                     );
```